# Dúvida com Firebase

Tags: firebase

Após ouvir falar do Firebase, e ler sobre, decidi que era uma boa ideia testar o seu uso no meu aplicativo Unity.

Li a documentação, segui os tutoriais de configuração, e inclusive defini as regras de autenticação para que mesmo usuários não autenticados pudessem incluir no banco de dados. Fiz o seguinte código apenas para motivos de teste

```
void Start()
{
    // Set up the Editor before calling into the realtime database.
    FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("https://magicast-bd2fc.firebaseio.com/");

    Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.StateChanged += DefaultInstance_StateChanged;

    // Get the root reference location of the database.
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;

    var u = new User();
    u.email = "sdjkdsdksadjsad";
    u.fb_id = "sakdsajdhasd";
    u.username = "jadhsjahjsda";
    reference.SetValueAsync(u);
}
```

Esse código é executado assim que rodo o projeto Unity, inclusive cai nos breakpoints.

Porém, ao olhar no Console Firebase da minha aplicação, na aba Database, não tem nada! E nenhum erro me é apresentado nesse código. Não consigo identificar o que estou fazendo de errado, e apesar de esse código ser em C#, pra Unity, creio que a lógica do Firebase é igual em todas as plataformas, então toda ajuda é bem vinda.

Alguma dica? Talvez alguma configuração a fazer, ou um pequeno código a adicionar

Comment: Bom amigo, verifique as regras do database, pode ser que esteja negado para quem não está autenticado, você pode gerar um email aleatorio para os usuarios desconhecidos, você pode gerar um email aleatorio para o usuario unknow.